# I cant find my DS160 number

Tags: visas

so i filled out a ds160 application. I than attempted to book an appointment to collect my visa but it says i need my unique  DS160 number. I never received one? anybody know how to sort this out?

Answer (score 3):

This number is on your barcode confirmation page that you were instructed to print when you completed your application. You need this page to book an appointment and you must also bring it to the consulate.